# How can I check if a key is in a dictionary on a django template?

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-templates

1. I am passing this dictionary to my template

   ```
   dict['Album'] = {'artist':'Beyonce','title':'hello','cover':'image'}
   ```
2. I want to write an `if` statement on my template to check if a key is in the dictionary
3. There are times when a cover is not into the dictionary
4. This is what I have tried

   ```
   {% if cover in Album %}
     do something
   {% else %}
     this dictionary as no key
   {% end %}
   ```

Comment: Use `{% if 'cover' in Album %}`, so a *string* literal.

Comment: Did you check if the key returned for none or the empty string?

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
 {% if 'cover' in Album %}
     do something
 {% else %}
     other statement
```

Comment: This usage of "in" keyword is not allowed in Django template.

Comment: This does not work. I just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply do as follows, conceptually similar to how it works in Python:

```
{% if Album.cover %}
  do something
{% else %}
  do something else
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This actually yields a template exception in the background. Better to check for existence before accessing.